# boto key.get_content throws socket.error and then fails on retry

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, httplib

I am using boto for uploading and downloading data from S3 bucket. I first check for key presence and then call download to file api of boto as follows.

```
    @retry_decorator
    def _get_data_to_file(self, src_key_object, file_name):
    try:
        s_key.get_contents_to_filename(file_name)
    except Exception, fault:
        logger.traceback(fault)
        raise
```

retry_decorator is decorator functions which helps to retry the operation if call fails. I observed following error in my traceback.

```
[2016-02-02 10:23:09,427] [ERROR] Error <class 'socket.error'>:[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer. Traceback -Traceback (most recent call last):
File "roboClientLib/boto/awsDRLib.py", line 1173, in _get_data_to_file
File "boto/s3/key.py", line 1712, in get_contents_to_filename
File "boto/s3/key.py", line 1650, in get_contents_to_file
File "boto/s3/key.py", line 1482, in get_file
File "boto/s3/key.py", line 1535, in _get_file_internal
File "boto/s3/key.py", line 386, in next
File "boto/connection.py", line 413, in read
File "httplib.py", line 542, in read
File "socket.py", line 377, in read
File "ssl.py", line 215, in recv
File "ssl.py", line 136, in read
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

[2016-02-02 10:23:39,459] [ERROR] Error <class 'httplib.IncompleteRead'>:IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 112795648 more expected). Traceback -Traceback (most recent call last):
File "roboClientLib/boto/awsDRLib.py", line 1173, in _get_data_to_file
File "boto/s3/key.py", line 1712, in get_contents_to_filename
File "boto/s3/key.py", line 1650, in get_contents_to_file
File "boto/s3/key.py", line 1482, in get_file
File "boto/s3/key.py", line 1535, in _get_file_internal
File "boto/s3/key.py", line 388, in next
File "boto/s3/key.py", line 370, in close
File "boto/connection.py", line 410, in read
File "httplib.py", line 529, in read
File "httplib.py", line 621, in _safe_read
IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 112795648 more expected)
```

and similar error continue for further retry. What i observed is first traceback show socket error while subsequent traceback of same call show something else..

Can anybody help to understand why i am able to execute the call after retry..?

Comment: This seems to be a reported issue, try reading this: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2207

Comment: still i couldn't figure out why this issue is coming but i refreshed the key object before retry and succeed to read/write. One more behavior which i noted that it is coming for file having size in MBs (may be > 50MB)